# Where can the new skin sets be obtained?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Just saw the new packs "Rising Sun Collection, Gods and Monsters Collection and Chop Shop Collection" and wondered where the skins in them come from. As far as I know, there is only one new case which only gives from Falchion Case Collection.

Does the new skins drop, or do they get unlocked from a case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the new skins you must have to buy OPERATION BLOODHOUND coin and then activate it so  you can access to mission and then when  you will get your first rank then  you will get weapon drop from these packs you are talking about.

There may be chance to get falchion case while playing cs go without buying OPERATION BLOODHOUND but then you must need key to open it but as i mentioned above, buy OPERATION BLOODHOUND and you will get weapon drop which won't need any key..

For more detail, read  [Here](http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/2015/05/11988/)

Thank you...

Comment: ardazkal, telling you one thing..dn't sell the case as it will worth 2$ but if you will buy key for it and open then there will be chance to get skins more then 15$ so all the best :)